# XPath expression to match across two associated elements

Tags: xpath

I’ve got the following XML of associated elements:

```
<doc>
  <!-- A block of style elements. -->
  <styles>
    <style id='style-1' class='bar'>…</style>
    <style id='style-2' class='baz'>…</style>
    …
  </styles>
  <!-- Document content. -->
  <p style='style-1'>…</p>
  <p style='style-2'>…</p>
  …
</doc>
```

For an [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) template I’m looking for an XPath expression matches “an element `p` whose style is of class `bar`”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure XPath 1.0 expression that will return *all elements p whose style is of class bar* :

```
//p[@style = //style[@class='bar']/@id]
```

Basically, the XPath looks for `<p>` elements where `style` attribute equals `id` of `<style class='bar'>`.

Comment: Please also consider [JLRishe’s answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49567802/xpath-expression-to-match-across-two-associated-elements#49568545) regarding performance considerations between the two solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that is an accurate representation of your document's structure, I would advise using this, without double-slashes (`//`) since double-slashes can be very inefficient:

```
/doc/p[@style = /doc/styles/style[@class = 'bar']/@id]
```

Comment: Thanks @JLRishe, I ran into these performance differences before and already adjusted the above expression accordingly. But good that you’ve pointed it out for other visitors!